# Not able to validate package installation on windows using inspec

Tags: windows, chef-infra, inspec

I want to know how to validate the installation of a package/application ( ON WINDOWS machine ) through inspec. 
I tried using package command to test but it didn't work.

Control :

describe package ('java') do
   it { should be_installed }
end

Error :

System Package java
     ×  System Package java should be installed
     expected that `System Package java` is installed

What's wrong here or are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe package 'Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 111 (64-bit)' do
  it { should be_installed }
end
```

The name of the package should be the one you see in "Programs and Features" in Control Panel.